# Label text doesn't change in IBAction method

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, label, action, uilabel

I'm trying to count how much time the user is holding his finger down on a button,
and to show this time in sec as the label.text...(up to 10 sec)
everything is working fine but the label.text updates in the end of the action
(i have only one button and one label...)

my header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CFData.h>
@interface TwisterViewController : UIViewController {
  UILabel *label;
  CFTimeInterval presstime;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
-(IBAction) fingeron;

@end
```

my m-file

```
#import "TwisterViewController.h"
@implementation TwisterViewController
@synthesize label;
-(IBAction) fingeron
{
  int holdtime;
  presstime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
  holdtime = (int) (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - presstime);
  NSString *holdtimetext; 
  while (holdtime <= 10) {
    holdtimetext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", holdtime];
    label.text = holdtimetext;
    holdtime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - presstime;
  }
  presstime = 0;
}
```

So the label.text is empty for 9 sec and in the and of the action it shows "10"

Answer (score 0):

Crete TImer for this

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(fingerOn) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

Then use Own Method

```
 -(IBAction) fingeron
    {
        int holdtime;
    presstime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    holdtime = (int) (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - presstime);
    NSString *holdtimetext; 
    while(holdtime <= 10)
    {
        holdtimetext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", holdtime];
        label.text = holdtimetext;
        holdtime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - presstime;
    }
    presstime = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do i put it? couse it didnt do anything

Comment: Try this on Viewdidload or ViewWillAppear Method of ViewController